# Cannot receive data when select and UDP protocol combined

Tags: c++, sockets, io, network-programming, udp

The original code for the UDP client is as shown below:

```
while (getline(cin, buf)) {
        // c.getConnd() return connected fd
        write(c.getConnfd(), buf.c_str(), buf.size());
        memset(cbuf, 0, sizeof(cbuf));
        read(c.getConnfd(), cbuf, 1024);
        LOG(DEBUG) << "read message: " << cbuf;
    }
```

It works fine, so neither server(using recvfrom and sendto) nor socket binding causes this problem.

To learn IO multiplex I write a class named `IOMultiplexingUtility`, which enable user combine a `fd` with respective callable object. After setting them it step into a infinite loop (find a readable fd - do some action - wait again):

```
class IOMultiplexingUtility {
public:
    IOMultiplexingUtility() {
        FD_ZERO(&socketSet);
    }

    void addFd(int fd, std::function<void(int)> action) {
        maxfd = fd + 1;
        FD_SET(fd, &socketSet);
        fdVec[fd] = action;
    }

    void start() {
        auto readySet = socketSet;
        select(maxfd + 1, &readySet, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        for (auto &pair: fdVec)
            if (FD_ISSET(pair.first, &readySet)) {
                if (pair.second != nullptr)pair.second(pair.first);
                else if (defaultAction) defaultAction(pair.first);
            }
    }

private:
    fd_set socketSet;
    int maxfd;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(int)>> fdVec;
};
```

Modified UDP client code like this:

```
io.addFd(c.getConnfd(), [&c](int)mutable -> void {
    char cbuf[1024];
    memset(cbuf, 0, sizeof(cbuf));
    read(c.getConnfd(), cbuf, 1024);
    cout << cbuf << endl;
});

io.addFd(fileno(stdin), [&c](int)mutable -> void {
    string buf;
    getline(cin, buf);
    write(c.getConnfd(), buf.c_str(), buf.size());
});

while (true) io.start();
```

Bug occurred (I input text, server receives and sends successfully, but `cbuf` never be outputted) and I can't figure out a way to resolve it. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a logic flaw in `addFd`. Should be something like `maxfd = std::max(fd, maxfd)`, as well as initialize `maxfd` to something like `INT_MIN` in the constructor.